# java:Adopting in algorithm?

Tags: java, android, algorithm

Birthday probability problem
here is the algorithm which i follow, bit i still face problem. The algorithm is

1. To simplify the problem, we make the assumption that each day of the year (except February 29) is equally likely for a birthday. We will only consider 365 days in a year.
2. When generating a random birthday for a person, generate a random integer in the range 0-364, each number will represent an individual day in a year (0 for January 1st, and 364 for December 31st). We will use zero-based numbers to match array indexing.
3. When performing a single simulation, remember you only need to find one pair of matching birthdays to make the simulation count. That is, as soon as you determine that two people have the same birthday you can stop the current simulation and start the next simulation.
4. To ensure that everyone’s program behaves the same (so that we can auto-grade everyone’s submission), you will need to create a new Random object for each simulation run, and you will need to seed the Random object with the number of the run you are simulating (the first simulation run will use the integer 1 as the seed, the second run will use 2, etc.). You need to create a new Random object per simulation run, not per random number needed [do not use the Math.random() method in this program].
5. During one simulation, you will need to keep track of the days which ``correspond to someone’s birthday, or alternatively keep track of the number of birthdays that occur on any given day. There are several structures that we studied in this module of the MOOC that could be used to easily solve this problem. You are free to pick the structure of your choice. Note that the goal is to simply determine if two birthdays land on the same date.
6. When returning the final result, return the percentage in the range 0.0 – 100.0.

enter code here

```
        import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Logic {
public static void process(int size, int count)
{
     int number = 0;
     Set<Integer> bdays = new HashSet<>();
     int x[] = new int[size];
     Random random = new Random();
     random.setSeed(1);

     int matches = 0;
     boolean out = false;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
             number=(random.nextInt(365)+1); 
          }
         for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                 if (bdays.contains(number))  {
                     matches++;
                 }
                  else
                     { bdays.add(number);
                 out = true;
                 break;}
           if (out) {
                 out = false;
                 break;
             }
         }
     }

        double prob = 100*(double) matches / count;
        System.out.println("The probability for two students to share a birthday is " + prob + ".");
        }



public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner inp = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("How many students?");
        int num = inp.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How many times?");
        int times = inp.nextInt();
   process(num,times);
}


}
```

Comment: So... what doesn't work in this code? What's your actual question?

Comment: Why is the c++ tag included?

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: Please turn to the help center to understand how to write up "this code doesn't work" questions. Hint: not like this.

Comment: if i give 20 group size and 10000 simulation then it give me 100 answer but the actual answer is 41.24 or some thing else.

Comment: And stop giving information in comments: update your question instead!

Comment: it not give me actual answer. if i give 20 group size and 10000 simulation then it give me 100 answer but the actual answer is 41.24 or some thing else.

Comment: for starter `random.nextInt(365)+1`  this contradicts this `generate a random integer in the range 0-364`

Comment: use `java.util.Random` to seed with the suggested numbers. The inner loop must be a kind of while (while not matching birthdays pick another random birthday...) You didn't give us the code that computes the percentage, etc.

Comment: know i change the code which compute the percentage but that percentage is not correct......please tell me where is actual problem...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there are a few things wrong, but here's the first one: You're always adding `number` to `bdays` as soon as you assign `number`. You then later check to see if `number` is in `bdays`, which of course it will be - thus why you get the 100% match rate. What you need to do is:

1. Pick `number`
2. Check if `number` is already in `bdays`, and increment the counter if it is
3. Add `number` to `bdays`

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
          number=(random.nextInt(365)+1); 
          }
         for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                 if (bdays.contains(number))  {
                     matches++;
                 }
                  else
                     { bdays.add(number);
                 out = true;
                 break;}
           if (out) {
                 out = false;
                 break;
             }
         }

Comment: that is the code which know i change it, but it still not give me the correct answer

Comment: @abubakaryousaf Does it give the same wrong answer, or a different wrong answer? (You'll get a better result if you give more descriptive info than "it doesn't work".)

Comment: it give a little bit different answer buut remain wrong answer

Comment: Is it wildly off, or sort-of similar?  Does it give the same wrong answer every time it runs? What values of "num" and "times" are you using?

Comment: in his problem i want to calculate the percentage of same birthday by giving the size of the group and the number of simulations run on that group.

Comment: i  am using 20 size and 10000 simulations, it show me 91.34 or some thing like this, but the actual vale is 41.32.

Comment: @abubakaryousaf Okay, I see the next problem - you have two separate inner loops. One of them just re-assigns number twenty times in a row without ever doing anything with the value (except the last time). You're also breaking out of the loop when you don't find a match, rather than when you do, you're not re-setting bdays between simulations, and you're not setting the random seed the way the instructions describe.

Comment: @abubakaryousaf I hope you don't mind some more general-philosophy advice, but I see you doing something a lot of the students I used to tutor did, and it won't work well. I think you're looking almost exclusively at your code, and trying to think about and fix that... this results in code that is basically bug soup. The code should only be a reflection of the algorithm; think about the algorithm, break it down into steps, and then try to figure out the syntax that reflects those steps. Try writing out pseudo-code for the algorithm, and I'll help you figure that out first.